# Reading HF RFID Tags using NFC in Win10 Universal Windows App

Tags: uwp, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

Below the sample Universal Win10 App code to read HF RFID Tag using NFC. The 'ReadTag' method is not triggered when device reads the RFID tag. I tried to change the Messagetype from NDEF to Windows with the same result. How can I read an RFID Tag using NFC in Univeral Windows App? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I read the same RFID tag successfully using an Android App with NFC enabled and specifying ISO 15693 tag.

The win10 code was compiled using VS2015 update 3 with capability 'Proximity' enabled and deployed on Microsoft Phone 950 NFC enabled.

```
private long _messageSubscribeId;
Windows.Networking.Proximity.ProximityDevice proximityDevice;
public MainPage()
{

InitializeComponent();

proximityDevice = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();

if (proximityDevice != null)
{
    proximityDevice.DeviceArrived += ProximityDeviceArrived;
    proximityDevice.DeviceDeparted += ProximityDeviceDeparted;

//subscribe....
    _messageSubscribeId = proximityDevice.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF",ReadTag);  
}
else
{
    MessageTextBlock.Text += "Failed to initialize proximity device.\n";
}
}

Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher _dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

private async void ProximityDeviceArrived(object sender)
{
await _dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
        MessageTextBlock.Text += "Proximate device arrived.\n";
});
}

private async void ProximityDeviceDeparted(object sender)
{
await _dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
        MessageTextBlock.Text += "Proximate device departed.\n";
});
} 

private void ReadTag(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
{
await _dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{            
        MessageTextBlock.Text += "Proximate device Read Tag\n";
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is not in the code, but on Windows SO dll (Windows.Networking.Proximity.dll). Unfortunately, there are no many documents published, that Windows 8 and Windows 10, only process NDEF format tags. This is most unfortunate, because it only works if the tag you want to access has been previously "published" as NDEF format.

check this link https://dotblogs.com.tw/pou/2013/05/07/103062 it helps a lot.